# Binary classification for a series of data (using Keras) to tell if it is a straight line or not a straight line

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am new to machine learning and I would like to seek some advice/help for directions on implementing a binary classification for a series of data and tell if it is a straight line or a not?

for example I have the following data e.g.

Training data:

- 0,2,4  -- straight line
- 0,10,5  -- not a straight line
- 0,99,99  -- not a straight line
- 0,1,2  -- straight line

My Validation data would be:

- 0,60,120 -- straight line
- 0,120,60 -- not a straight line